# Backbone Marionette: parameters undefined in view (data is defined)

Tags: collections, requirejs, underscore.js, fetch, marionette

The data that I'm trying to pass to my template is inexplicably ignored when it gets to underscore's [template renderer](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.4.4/underscore.js#L1164).

The data is available:

[image: underscore.js in dev console just before fail]

Yet I get an exception in the console that the param `url` is undefined:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

If I drill a bit deeper, I get to some crazy-looking javascript:

[image: UnderscoreJS's Renderer on template]

It fails immediately after: `__p+='\n\t\t<a href="#'+` (notice `url` and `label` are still both defined).

Comment: That "crazy-looking javascript" is the compiled version of your template. If your template says `<%= url %>` then you must pass it a `url` value or you'll get a ReferenceError. Perhaps a functional example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would be helpful.

Comment: Normally there would be a `with(obj||{})` in the compiled template. I don't see one in yours so perhaps the [`variable` option](http://underscorejs.org/#template) is in use somewhere (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jrEub/) so you'd have to say `<%= E.url %>` or something like that in the template.

Comment: @muistooshort, you were exactly right! `E.url`. what a pain! Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @muistooshort, would you put that into an answer so I can approve/resolve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there would be a `with(obj||{})` in the compiled template. I don't see one in yours so perhaps the [`variable` option](http://underscorejs.org/#template) is in use somewhere:

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting.

For example, if you:

```
var t = _.template('<%= x %>');
```

and then look at `t.source`, you'll see a function like this (formatted for clarity):

```
function(obj){
    //...
    with(obj||{}){
        //...
    }
    return __p;
}
```

but if you say:

```
var t = _.template('<%= x %>', null, { variable: 'E' });
```

and look at `t.source`, you'll see the same structure *without* the `with` block around the guts of the function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jrEub/

The structure of the template function suggests that you have `{variable: 'E'}` somewhere so your template should be look at `<% E.url %>` and such instead of just `<% url %>`.